# Convert pandas dataframe to array of series

Tags: python, pandas

The now-deprecated `to_matrix` and *values* would provide arrays from a *dataframe*.  However I want to work with the "features" of a dataframe - which means working with the columns as *Series*. How can a list of *Series* be extracted from the *dataframe* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need transpose the return from `.values`

```
df.values.T.tolist()
Out[1321]: 
[['a1', 'a3', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a4', 'a1'],
 ['c1', 'c1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c5']]
```

Or just

```
df.values.T
Out[1322]: 
array([['a1', 'a3', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a4', 'a1'],
       ['c1', 'c1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c5']],
      dtype=object)
```

If need list of `Series` we can also do `groupby`

```
[y for _,y in df.groupby(level=0,axis=1)]
Out[1328]: 
[  airport
 0      a1
 1      a3
 2      a1
 3      a1
 4      a2
 5      a2
 6      a3
 7      a4
 8      a4
 9      a1,   carrier
 0      c1
 1      c1
 2      c1
 3      c2
 4      c2
 5      c2
 6      c3
 7      c4
 8      c5
 9      c5]
```

---

Data input

```
df
Out[1329]: 
  airport carrier
0      a1      c1
1      a3      c1
2      a1      c1
3      a1      c2
4      a2      c2
5      a2      c2
6      a3      c3
7      a4      c4
8      a4      c5
9      a1      c5
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a list comprehension:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(some_data)

mat = [df[col].values for col in df.columns]
```

Where `df[col].values` returns a `Series` of the values from a given column

Comment: Ya I was hunting for this but could not put my finger on it (tick tock 7 mins..)

Answer (score 2):

Can get a list of Series with `.to_dict('Series')`, just taking the values.

```
list(df.to_dict('Series').values())

[0    a1
 1    a3
 2    a1
 3    a1
 4    a2
 5    a2
 6    a3
 7    a4
 8    a4
 9    a1
 Name: airport, dtype: object, 0    c1
 1    c1
 2    c1
 3    c2
 4    c2
 5    c2
 6    c3
 7    c4
 8    c5
 9    c5
 Name: carrier, dtype: object]
```

Each element of the list is a Series:

```
type(list(df.to_dict('Series').values())[0])
#pandas.core.series.Series
```

Answer (score 1):

You can track much of the same information (different dtypes between Series, names of Series) in a `numpy` structured array that you can in a DataFrame.  Pandas has a convenient way of doing this.  I am using @Wen's sample data.

---

```
u = df.to_records(index=False)
```

```
rec.array([('a1', 'c1'), ('a3', 'c1'), ('a1', 'c1'), ('a1', 'c2'),
           ('a2', 'c2'), ('a2', 'c2'), ('a3', 'c3'), ('a4', 'c4'),
           ('a4', 'c5'), ('a1', 'c5')],
          dtype=[('airport', 'O'), ('carrier', 'O')])
```

---

```
u['airport']
```

```
array(['a1', 'a3', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a4', 'a1'],
      dtype=object)
```

Comment: in the 2nd code snippet should the `rec.array` be `u.array` ?

Comment: No, that's just the `__repr__` of a structured array.

Comment: ah.  i usually keep that in the same code block. thx for the clarification